# Scrollable BarChart with possibility to touch each bar using MpAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm trying to create a chart in my app using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).

My aim is to get a graph looking like this one:
[image]

But with some specific features.

- The graph will be wider than the screen's width so it must have a minimum width and be scrollable ( for the width I'm using this workaround, but its not scrollable ): `chart.getLayoutParams().width=100*entries.size();`
- I would like to have the same kind of speech bubble on click on a bar ( I don't know if there is a way to have it and the scroll in the same time since for the scroll I guess a workaround using layout and scrollview is the only solution if this feature is not implemented yet)
- and finally, when touching above one of the bar, not selecting the bar under ( which could prevent the user to scroll if there is a way to do so! ).

  Is it technically possible with MPAndroidChart yet? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is. And please do not use `ScrollView`.

Read this for modifying the viewport and "making the chart wider": https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Modifying-the-Viewport

The "speech bubble" you are talking about is the `MarkerView`, and yes, it can be displayed when scrolling as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I'm gonna see that. By the way thanks also for this library, it's really great!

Comment: @Virthuss did you implement it successful? Is this possible with scroll vertically?